# why does the JSON response imperfect in Volley Android?

Tags: java, android, request, http-post, android-volley

My complete response in Postman is the following but I can't get a complete response as JSON when using Volley android.

[image]

My volley code :

I have no problem sending a request but I show my logic that maybe was a problem with my code.

```
    public void makeAssignment(final String token,   HashMap<String,String> info_doc , List<Region> result, final OnMakeAssignment onMakeAssignment) {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("document_type", info_doc.get("type_doc"));
        params.put("title", info_doc.get("title_doc"));
        params.put("meter", info_doc.get("meter_doc"));
        params.put("price", info_doc.get("price_frosh"));
        params.put("mortgage_price", info_doc.get("vagozari_price_rahn")); // رهن
        params.put("monthly_rent_price", info_doc.get("vagozari_price_ejareh")); // ejareh
        params.put("address", info_doc.get("address"));
        params.put("description", info_doc.get("vagozari_description"));
        params.put("region[0]", "1");

        if (result.isEmpty()){
            params.put("region[0]", "all");
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                params.put("region["+i+"]", String.valueOf(result.get(i).getId()));
            }
        }

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Vars.MAKE_ASSIGNMENT,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        onMakeAssignment.onReceived(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError || error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NoInternet.class));
                            onMakeAssignment.onError(error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                params.put(Vars.KEY_AUTH, Vars.AUTH);
                 params.put(Vars.KEY_AUTH, token);
                params.put(Vars.KEY_USERNAME, Vars.USERNAME);
                params.put(Vars.KEY_PASSWORD, Vars.PASSWORD);
                return params;
            }


            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
          
                return params;
            }


        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
     

    }
```

The JSON response details are imperfect when I call this method with the Volley library but a response in the Postman is complete. so finally o don't know why this happens because it isn't a problem in requests when using PostMan. so my android Logcat gets back this response when running a method request but unfortunately it isn't the same as the response Postman.

> I/resewssssssss: {"clients":[{"id":44,"name":null,"mobile":null,"mobile_confirmed":0,"invited":0,"device_id":"null","firebase_token":"","device_serial":"","credit":"0","city_id":null,"region_id":null,"state_id":null,"api_token":"Basic LUnrhilQIWfdY6YQr6lxWCuZ8TAtNs4ailckURW6MG","client_type":1,"created_at":"2020-07-22T12:27:41.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-22T12:27:41.000000Z","credit_date":null,"description":null,"assignment_active":1,"assignment_reason":null,"visited":null,"property_request_active":1,"property_request_reason":null,"properties_count":6,"client_regions":[{"id":69,"client_id":44,"region_id":1}]},{"id":43,"name":null,"mobile":null,"mobile_confirmed":0,"invited":0,"device_id":"null","firebase_token":"","device_serial":"","credit":"0","city_id":null,"region_id":null,"state_id":null,"api_token":"Basic jwfz4Ll1YYE3oG4ZFDtAQEgufW4q2ZozEr3LUJU0q58","client_type":1,"created_at":"2020-07-22T11:59:49.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-22T11:59:49.000000Z","credit_date":null,"description":null,"assignment_active":1,"assignment_reason":null,"visited":null,"property_request_active":1,"property_request_reason":null,"properties_count":2,"client_regions":[{"id":68,"client_id":43,"region_id":1}]},{"id":31,"name":null,"mobile":null,"mobile_confirmed":0,"invited":0,"device_id":"null","firebase_token":"","device_serial":"","credit":"0","city_id":null,"region_id":null,"state_id":null,"api_token":"Basic SI3FWNH1mxg8N4JL0HEu45nEqlUBtEv
> JQbRdmpuR4CeKcJ0","client_type":1,"created_at":"2020-07-20T16:01:48.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-20T16:01:48.000000Z","credit_date":null,"description":null,"assignment_active":1,"assignment_reason":null,"visited":null,"property_request_active":1,"property_request_reason":null,"properties_count":1,"client_regions":[{"id":51,"client_id":31,"region_id":1}]},{"id":33,"name":null,"mobile":null,"mobile_confirmed":0,"invited":0,"device_id":"null","firebase_token":"","device_serial":"","credit":"0","city_id":null,"region_id":null,"state_id":null,"api_token":"Basic nOwhIwlowhqgQUXEHH8heXSmM
> iJOqNEoJiVb6TKwO381Yp","client_type":1,"created_at":"2020-07-20T20:05:22.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-20T20:05:22.000000Z","credit_date":null,"description":null,"assignment_active":1,"assignment_reason":null,"visited":null,"property_request_active":1,"property_request_reason":null,"properties_count":1,"client_regions":[{"id":53,"client_id":33,"region_id":1},{"id":54,"client_id":33,"region_id":118}]},{"id":34,"name":null,"mobile":"09123456789","mobile_confirmed":0,"invited":0,"device_id":"null","firebase_token":"","device_serial":"","credit":"0","city_id":null,"region_id":null,"state_id":null,"api_token":"Basic DkCrb8tzrt5FKldXon0xm8d
> e2fLpugea61lVRnOR3IATSfb","client_type":1,"created_at":"2020-07-20T20:51:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-21T18:08:46.000000Z","credit_date":null,"description":null,"assignment_active":1,"assignment_reason":null,"visited":null,"property_request_active":1,"property_request_reason":null,"properties_count":1,"client_regions":[{"id":55,"client_id":34,"region_id":1}]},{"id":1,"name":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631 \u062a\u0633\u062a","mobile":null,"mobile_confirmed":0,"invited":0,"device_id":null,"firebase_token":null,"device_serial":null,"credit":"0","city_id":1,"region_id":null,"state_id":1,"api_token":"Basic a142pbR0LGvfaZFi6333ZIj5pghgyzsFmGiNvn4k4CwzRi6g","client_type":1,"created_at":"2020-07-02T13:16:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-05-21T02:48:02.000000Z","credit_date":"2021-05-18","description":"ttewtwt","assignment_active":1,"assignment_reason":null,"visited":null,"property_request_active":1,"property_request_reason":null,"properties_count":0,"client_regions":[{"id":1,"client_id":1,"region_id":1},{"id":2,"client_id":1,"region_id":2},{"id":3,"client_id":1,"region_id":3}]},{"id":9,"name":null,"mobile":null,"mobile_confirmed":0,"invited":0,"device_id":"null","firebase_token":"","device_serial":"","credit":"0","city_id":null,"region_id":null,"state_id":null,"api_token"

Comment: because of the limit of logcat log ? save to the file instead and check then (or just show in log in 4k chunks)

Comment: Yes, @Selvin right there is a limit to logcat log, but you can check your full response by adding a breakpoint in  onResponse method

Comment: as I wrote ... log to file or log in chunks

Comment: you can also increase the logger buffer size in the Developer options